# How to convert rows to column in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to retrieve output format but only one column able to bind. I'm working in Sql server 2008 R2. I'm working for last 2 days but I can't seem to bind it. I need this without using pivot and unpivot function.

**Table:**

```
   | AAA    |   AA+     |    AA     |     AA-
   ---------------------------------------------
A  | 6.05   |   7.15    |    9.5    |     8.5
B  | 3.02   |   4.58    |    6.25   |     7.25
C  | 2.25   |   1.02    |    0      |     6
```

**Output:**

```
No  |  A    |   B   |  C
----------------------------
AAA |  6.05 |  3.02 |  2.25
AA+ |  4.05 |  3.04 |  1.02
AA  |  3.02 |  4.05 |  0
AA- |  2.03 |  3.01 |  6
```

Comment: "Without using pivot and unpivot" might be very hard. Why can't you use them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` and conditional aggregation:

```
select v.no,
       max(case when t.col = 'A' then v.val end) as a,
       max(case when t.col = 'B' then v.val end) as b,
       max(case when t.col = 'C' then v.val end) as c
from t cross apply
     (values ('AAA', AAA), ('AA+', [AA+]), ('AA', AA), ('AA-', [AA-])
) v(no, val)
group by v.no;
```

Comment: Hi,this query is not return a value, it shows like null for all columns

Comment: The only way I could imagine that is if the column used for the `when` does not take on the values `'A'`, `'B'`, and `'C'`.